# Should a COBOL generated file have an exact correspondence to a record layout file?

Tags: cobol

I am working with a company who asked their vendor for a data dump of all their information.  The vendor gave them flat files, and record layouts.  However, these layouts seem generic - for instance, they say the end of the file should be column 1400, but I'm at 1540 on each line.

Should there be a 1:1 correspondence between these data files and record layouts?  If so, does it sound like we got generic layouts for their "system" and not the ones specific to this company?

Comment: It's possible that the vendor gave you older record layouts that don't match the current flat files.

Comment: You mean the end of the record, not the end of the file? Yes, you'd expect a good correspondence, in general, but it is not a law. We don't even know the type of vendor, or the type of data. If it is proprietary information, or the 1401 to 1540 data is, then they may not want to tell you. However, we don't know anywhere near enough to make any useful comments, and your question is off-topic unless you can make it about programming, somehow.

Comment: @BillWoodger Right, the layout says each record should end at the 1400 character mark, but there is plenty more data after that... and if there are better specifics I can provide, please inform me - I'm a Cobol newb. I realize the question is not about syntax or specific approach, but it is definitely about programming in the sense that I need to know if layouts should match data output so I can automate the translation in another language. Are there any Cobol beginner resources you would recommend?

Comment: What OS and compiler are you using? What type of system does the vendor supply?

Comment: If it is Cobol, the files will match the Cobol copybook's used to write them. If there is binary data, there could be minor variations in the format depending on the Compiler used.

Comment: One other possibility -- is it possible your file went through a character conversion between the vendor and you and some of the characters were translated into multibyte characters, like UTF-8?  That could increase record length and throw off your Cobol copybook.

Comment: Is it a variable length file or fixed length file?

Comment: Could there have been a delimiter character added between each of the fields? That would add to the record length and the record layout could be said to "match" the data. But yes, as everyone is saying, you need the record layout that exactly matches the data. Ask the vendor for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Try to "take the pulse" of the data file by matching up the data file and layout at a couple of points.

For example, if there is a Last Name in columns 352 to 381, followed by a Phone Number in columns 382 to 391, do you see that which appears to be a Last Name and Phone Number in the respective columns?

Try the right edge of the data file and layout first. Sometimes you get lucky and there's two distinct columns of data at the right edge.  Then try the midpoint, around column 750.

If you have something to push back to the vendor, they are more likely to respond since you're giving them something to work with.